# How to center the Y axis label in scatter chart?

Tags: label, echarts, yaxis

Currently the Y axis labels are align with the "axisLine":

[not centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qokg3.png)

Is there a way to make them row centered like in the photo:

[centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXu6Z.png)

Default example of scatter chart: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=scatter-simple

Comment: have you had a go at using this option?  https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.nameTextStyle.verticalAlign

Comment: @KeoooDev Yes, I've tried all options in the API documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem when I changed the yAxis type to "category":

`yAxis: {type:"category"}`